# Problem with Image Texture using Bump and Displacement (Cycle Render)

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I'm trying to follow a star destroyer tutorial made by CG Geek and I've reached the point where I'm using Image Textures for the side. For some reason in rendered, the image texture looks quite odd as you can see in the image below... does anyone know why its like this? Also, how can I rotate the image texture cause its vertical in render

The first screenshot is how the star destroyer should look rendered (from tutorial)

[Link to the tutorial video by CG Geek](https://youtu.be/A245FOyn9Ak?t=359)
[image: How the star destroyer should looked rendered]

The two remaining screenshots are from my project

[image: Render view of the star destroyer]
[image: Face orientation of the star destroyer]

Comment: hello please pack the image and share your file; https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: The displacement is happening in all XYZ. Add a 'Displacement' node after the texture should be fixed. https://youtu.be/arvhK4tvYuY?t=786

Comment: Thanks @MAJacob. I added a displacement node before but it still seemed wrong until I changed the scale to 0.1 instead of 1. Thanks to everyone that helped!